# SharePoint Initial Configuration on Azure non-HA?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-resource-manager

I installed a new non-HA SharePoint farm using Azure Resource Manager GUI. Logging onto the SP server, there is no "configure this server" shortcut on the desktop. I then tried to re-install the server using an ARM template, but again there is no apparent way to get the server running with some simple team sites. What is the right recipe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer -

1. Log onto the server as %declareddomain.tld%\%sharepointfarmusername%
   via RDP.
2. Browse to http://%servername%:8080/default.aspx

The various documents I found online specified port 80, 8080, 8181, 15000, etc etc. But that appears to work. Hope it helps the next person struggling to start - all of the tutorials I could find encompassed steps to start up the farm, but not actually configure it to *do* anything.

Thanks.